# How to fix asp.net connection to make data shown up in razor page?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2022

I have code my connection and call my db with c# code with code like below but when i debug my webapp the page not loaded the data that i've called in the razor page. I have tried hard to look for the answer by the google but nothing give me solution for this error. Please help me, still new in c# and asp.net .NET framework
`

```
namespace Data_Penduduk.Pages.Master
{

    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<DataOrang> listOrang = new List<DataOrang>();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MySource;Integrated Security=True";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM datas";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                DataOrang dataOrang = new DataOrang();
                                dataOrang.NIK = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
                                dataOrang.Nama = reader.GetString(1);
                                dataOrang.JK = reader.GetString(2);
                                dataOrang.TL = reader.GetString(3);
                                dataOrang.Alamat = reader.GetString(4);
                                dataOrang.Negara = reader.GetString(5);

                                listOrang.Add(dataOrang);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    public class DataOrang
    {
        public String NIK;
        public String Nama;
        public String JK;
        public String TL;
        public String Alamat;
        public String Negara;
    }
}
```

`

`

```
<tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model.listOrang)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.NIK</td>
                <td>@item.Nama</td>
                <td>@item.JK</td>
                <td>@item.TL</td>
                <td>@item.Alamat</td>
                <td>@item.Negara</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="text-warning">Detail</a>
                    <a href="#" class="text-info">Edit</a>
                    <a href="#" class="text-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

`

i have tried to change the constructor but it doesnt work

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint to see  the value of  `listOrang`. What's the value of it?

Comment: just a suggestion, avoid `select *` and define the connection string in some config file